# Hangfire - Multi tenant, ASP.NET Core - Resolving the correct tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, hangfire

I got a SaaS project that needs the use Hangfire. We already implemented the requirements to identify a tenant.

**Architecture**

- Persistence Layer

  - Each tenant has it's own database
- .NET Core

  - We already have a service `TenantCurrentService` which returns the ID of the tenant, from a list of source [hostname, query string, etc]
  - We already have a `DbContextFactory` for Entity Framework which return a DB context with the correct connection string for the client
  - We are currently using ASP.NET Core DI (willing to change if that helps)
- Hangfire

  - Using single storage (eg: Postgresql), no matter the tenant count
  - Execute the job in an appropriate Container/ServiceCollection, so we retrieve the right database, right settings, etc.

**The problem**

I'm trying to stamp a TenantId to a job, retrieved from `TenantCurrentService` (which is a Scoped service).

When the job then gets executed, we need to retrieve the `TenantId` from the Job and store it in `HangfireContext`, so then the `TenantCurrentService` knows the TenantId retrieved from Hangfire. And from there, our application layer will be able to connect to the right database from our `DbContextFactory`

**Current state**

- Currently, we have been able to store tenantId retrieved from our Service using a `IClientFilter`.
- How can I retrieve my current ASP.NET Core DI ServiceScope from IServerFilter (which is responsible to retrieve the saved Job Parameters), so I can call .GetRequiredService().IdentifyTenant(tenantId)

Is there any good article regarding this matter / or any tips that you guys can provide?

Comment: sounds like you have a lot sorted out with Hangfire & ASP.NET core DI. Can you point me to any articles that describe the complex bits? Currently I'm having trouble with executing the job in an appropriate Container/ServiceCollection so it gets dependencies differently when processing jobs than when processing web requests. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618098/hangfire-dependency-injection-with-net-core-inject-different-objects-when-proc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you need to be able to set the `TenantId` in your `TenantCurrentService`.
Then, you can rely on filters :

client side (where you enqueue jobs)

```
public class ClientTenantFilter : IClientFilter
{
        public void OnCreating(CreatingContext filterContext)
        {
           if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));

            filterContext.SetJobParameter("TenantId", TenantCurrentService.TenantId);
        }
}
```

and server side (where the job is dequeued).

```
public class ServerTenantFilter : IServerFilter
{
    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
    {
      if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));

      var tenantId = filterContext.GetJobParameter<string>("TenantId");
      TenantCurrentService.TenantId = tenantId;
    }
}
```

The server filter can be declared when you configure your server through an `IJobFilterProvider`:

```
        var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
        {
            Queues = ...,
            FilterProvider = new ServerFilterProvider()
        };
        app.UseHangfireServer(storage, options, ...);
```

where ServerFilterProvider is :

```
public class ServerFilterProvider : IJobFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<JobFilter> GetFilters(Job job)
    {
        return new JobFilter[]
                   {
                       new JobFilter(new CaptureCultureAttribute(), JobFilterScope.Global, null),
                       new JobFilter(new ServerTenantFilter (), JobFilterScope.Global,  null),
                   };
    }
}
```

The client filter can be declared when you instantiate a BackgroundJobClient

```
var client = new BackgroundJobClient(storage, new BackgroundJobFactory(new ClientFilterProvider());
```

where `ClientFilterProvider` behaves as `ServerFilterProvider`, delivering client filter

A difficulty may be to have the TenantCurrentService available in the filters. I guess this should be achievable by injecting factories in the FilterProviders and chain it to the filters.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer! I'm now able to stamp the TenantId in the Job's Parameters using a `IClientFilter`. How can I retrieve my current `ASP.NET Core DI ServiceScope` from `IServerFilter` (which is responsible to retrieve the saved Job Parameters), so I can call `.GetRequiredService<ITenantCurrentService>().IdentifyTenant(tenantId)`

Comment: @Dekim I don't know. I don't use HF with Aspnet Core. Maybe you should include ServiceScope, or a factory to it in your FilterProvider which can then provide it to the Filter

Comment: @dekim did you figure this bit out?