# How to run background workers simultaneously for multi tenancy in ABP framework

Tags: backgroundworker, hangfire, abp

I'm using ABP framework (version 5.3.3) for my project. I have 2 tenants with separate databases on different servers. My project has a task needs to run every 5 minutes to call a stored procedure in database of each tenant but I don't know how to run that task with background worker simultaneously for those tenants? I know that Hangfire can process multiple queues but how to configure to achieve my purpose?

Hope that my question is clear and appreciate for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your scheduled task should be :

- loop over your list of tenants
- foreach tenant, enqueue a background task which will run your stored procedure for this tenant

As far as I know (I don't know ABP), you don't need anything else to achieve your goal

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I knew that. But as I said above, my tenants are on different servers. I don't know how to change connection string when executing the task.

Comment: @duyan this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/66659597/1236044