# Tenant isNull in BackgroundJob

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire, abp

I have a background job where i need to have tenantId.

I did authenticate and I tested the tenantId, it is not null. I used other endpoints and it works wonderful but when I test the backgroundjob tenantId is always null.

I don't know if I am missing something or I need to send tenantId in the args.

This is the BJ

```
public class BackgroundNotificationJob : AsyncBackgroundJob<NotificationArgs>, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly FirebaseAppService _firebaseAppService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;

    public BackgroundNotificationJob (
         FirebaseAppService firebaseAppService ,
         IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager)
    {
        _firebaseAppService = firebaseAppService;
        _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync (NotificationArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var notification in args.Notifications)
        {
            await _firebaseAppService.CreateMessage(notification.Key, notification.Value.ToString(), args.UserId);
        }
    }
}
```

The config:

```
public override void ConfigureServices ( ServiceConfigurationContext context )
{
        var configuration = context.Services.GetConfiguration();
        ConfigureHangfire(context, configuration);
}

private void ConfigureHangfire (ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
{
        context.Services.AddHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.UseSqlServerStorage(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
        });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to send tenantId in the args and set current tenant in your job.

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57396553/1236044