# How to get a Hangfire Job Parameter into the method that is executed by that job

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-tenant, hangfire

I have installed Hangfire in an ASP.Net Core 5 web application.
I followed the [Getting Started](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html) guide on the Hangfire website and the initial installation and configuration were quick and it works.

As it is a multitenant application (DB per tenant) I need to be able to connect to the right database when the job is processed on the server.

I came across [this well explained post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57396553/9696383) which is exactly what I need as far as I can tell but I can't figure out the last step which is how to get the value from the job parameter (the tenant identification) into the method that Hangfire is executing.

I have created the Client filter

```
#region Hangfire Job Filters
#region Client filters
public class HfClientTenantFilter : IClientFilter
{
    private readonly IMultiTenant _multiTenant;
    public HfClientTenantFilter(IMultiTenant multiTenant)
    {
        _multiTenant = multiTenant;
    }
    public async void OnCreating(CreatingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));

        MdxTenantConfig tenantConfig = await _multiTenant.GetTenantConfig();
        filterContext.SetJobParameter("TenantId", tenantConfig.Id);
    }

    public void OnCreated(CreatedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));
    }
}

public class HfClientFilterProvider : IJobFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IMultiTenant _multiTenant;
    public HfClientFilterProvider(IMultiTenant multiTenant) {
        _multiTenant = multiTenant;
    }
    public IEnumerable<JobFilter> GetFilters(Job job)
    {
        return new JobFilter[]
        {
            new JobFilter(new CaptureCultureAttribute(), JobFilterScope.Global, null),
            new JobFilter(new HfClientTenantFilter(_multiTenant),JobFilterScope.Global, null)
        };
    }
}
#endregion Client filters
```

and Server filter:

```
#region Server filters
public class HfServerTenantFilter : IServerFilter
{
    private readonly IHfTenantProvider _hfTenantProvider;
    public HfServerTenantFilter(IHfTenantProvider hfTenantProvider)
    {
        _hfTenantProvider = hfTenantProvider;
    }

    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));

        var tenantId = filterContext.GetJobParameter<string>("TenantId");
        // need to get the tenantId passed to the method that calls the creation of the DbContext
        _hfTenantProvider.HfSetTenant(tenantId);
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));
    }
}

public class HfServerFilterProvider : IJobFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IHfTenantProvider _hfTenantProvider;
    public HfServerFilterProvider(IHfTenantProvider hfTenantProvider)
    {
        _hfTenantProvider = hfTenantProvider;
    }
    public IEnumerable<JobFilter> GetFilters(Job job)
    {
        return new JobFilter[]
        {
            new JobFilter(new CaptureCultureAttribute(), JobFilterScope.Global, null),
            new JobFilter(new HfServerTenantFilter(_hfTenantProvider), JobFilterScope.Global,  null),
        };
    }
}
#endregion Server filters
#endregion Hangfire Job Filters
```

Attaching the Server filter in Startup

```
services.AddHangfireServer(opt => {
                opt.FilterProvider = new HfServerFilterProvider(new HfTenantProvider());  
});
```

When executing in debug I see that the parameter `TenantID` is correctly set in the client filter and also correctly retrieved by the server filter.
I am now trying to make that value available to the method that is being executed but hasn't succeeded yet.
I tried using a scoped service:

```
#region Scoped Tenant provider service

public interface IHfTenantProvider {
    void HfSetTenant(string TenantCode);
    string HfGetTenant();
}

public class HfTenantProvider: IHfTenantProvider
{
    public string HfTenantCode;

    public void HfSetTenant(string TenantCode)
    {
        HfTenantCode = TenantCode;
    }

    public string HfGetTenant()
    {
        return HfTenantCode;
    }
}
#endregion Scoped Tenant provider service
```

and in Startup:

```
services.AddScoped<IHfTenantProvider, HfTenantProvider>();
```

In the `OnPerforming` method of the Server filter, I set the value in the Scoped service as retrieved from the Job Parameter (see above for full code) which is working as I can see in debugging.

```
_hfTenantProvider.HfSetTenant(tenantId);
```

This is the test method being scheduled:

```
public bool HfTest()
{
    try
    {
        BackgroundJobClient jobClient = GetJobClient();
        jobClient.Enqueue<MdxMetaCRUD>(crud => crud.HfTest());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is the method itself where I retrieve the value from the Scoped service which is, however `null`:

```
public async Task HfTest()
{
    string tenant =_hfTenantProvider.HfGetTenant();
    using (var _dbContext = _contextHelper.CreateContext(true, tenant))
    {
        Entity entity = new()
        {
            Name = "HFtest",
            Description = tenant,
            DefaultAuditTrackRetention = 1
        };
        await _dbContext.Entities.AddAsync(entity);
    }
}
```

The ContextHelper returns a new DbContext:

```
public ApplicationDbContext CreateContext(bool backgroundProcess, string backgroundTenant)
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext(_multiTenant, backgroundProcess, backgroundTenant);
}
```

The DbContext has an override to retrieve the connection string for the tenant (which is working fine in the user context). In case of a Job being executed by Hangfire, I am trying to pass the `TenantId` into `_backgroundTenant`

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    try
    {
        MdxTenantConfig tenantConfig = Task.Run(() => _multiTenant.GetTenantConfig(_backgroundProcess, _backgroundTenant)).Result;
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(tenantConfig.ConnectionString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
    catch //(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I was hoping that the Job being launched (Server filters being retrieved) and the Job being executed were in the same scope (request) but it seems not.
Am I doing something wrong with the scoped service or is my approach wrong? I saw some articles referring to a "factory" but that is beyond my knowledge (for the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try implementing your `HfTenantProvider` like this :

```
public class HfTenantProvider : IHfTenantProvider
{
    private static System.Threading.AsyncLocal<string> HfTenantCode { get; } = new System.Threading.AsyncLocal<string>();

    public void HfSetTenant(string TenantCode)
    {
        HfTenantCode.Value = TenantCode;
    }

    public string HfGetTenant()
    {
        return HfTenantCode.Value;
    }
}
```

I agree that this makes the scoping of the `HfTenantProvider` somewhat useless.
Also, you may call `HfSetTenant(null)` in the `OnPreformed` method of your server filter. I think this is cleaner, even though this should not make big difference.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect!!
In the meanwhile I have found a much simpler solution (for my scenario) that doesn't involve any of the Job Parameters/Filters. I will post it as well for others that are looking for a solution but I'll accept your answer as it is the correct solution for my original question.
And I will do some reading to fully understand your solution :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, the answer of @jbl is correct and works exacly as I requested in my original question. I hope this is useful for others.
I have however found a simpler solution in which I don't need Job Paramters or Filters and that fits my scenario. As I've seen that a lot of people are looking for guidance when implementing Hangfire in a multitenant environment I'm posting this solution as well and hope that it can help some people as well.

I my case the scheduling of the job is done by the user through the UI. This means that I **always** know the tenant when the job is scheduled.
So I simply pass the tenant id as a parameter to the method that is scheduled.
Instead of scheduling the job as:

```
backgroundClient.Enqueue<MyClass>(c => c.MyMethod(taskId)):
```

I schedule the job as following:

```
string tenantCode = _multiTenant.GetTenant();
backgroundClient.Enqueue<MyClass>(c => c.MyMethod(taskId, tenantCode)):
```

where `_multiTenant` is my implementation to retrieve the tenant id from `HttpContextAccessor`.

To execute the method against the correct database context I just need to pass `tenantId` when creating DbContext.

```
public async Task MyMethod(int taskId, string tenantCode)
{
    using (var _dbContext = _contextHelper.CreateContext(true, tenantCode))
    {
        ...
```

The override `OnConfiguring` of my DbContext can then fetch the tenant configuration (which includes the datasource string) straightaway.