# How to change hangfire connection string at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, connection-string, dbcontext, hangfire

I set connection string in startup.cs but I need to change dbContext and hangfire connectionString according to httpContext request. I have some idea about dbContext but I don't have any idea about hangfire connString. How can I do this? Thanks.

My code in startup.cs like this:

```
var connStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

services.AddDbContext<ExampleContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connStr));
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(connStr));
services.AddHangfireServer();
```

I want to change "DefaultConnection" according to "HttpContext.Request.Host.Host".

Comment: Why would you even have multiple Hangfire databases though? The problem here is all this config is done at app startup, not during a request.

Comment: However, this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394712/hangfire-multi-tenant-asp-net-core-resolving-the-correct-tenant

Comment: I will use a common api file and I will run this api on different IIS sites. Each site owner has own database. I cannot know which connection string belong to whom before first request. If I can do config in Configure method, it can be helpfull but I don't know how can I do there config settings for hangfire.

Comment: See https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/index.html